# PCI-E HBA on only PCI-E x16 slot on motherboard?

Tags: sas, hardware, pci-express, hba

I read a post maybe last week that said you can't put a HBA card on the only x16 slot on motherboard that doesn't have onboard video. Is there any truth to this?

I have a Gigabyte GA-965P-DS3/e6400 C2D/8GB DDR2 hanging around that would work find right now for my FreeNAS building i'm currently working on. I have a PRC-4220 case on the way. I know this will limit how many drives i can control since i really need 4x SFF-8087 ports (or 2 of the cards) but thats ok for now. I don't have that many drives now and as soon as i hit the limit i will either upgrade my motherboard/cpu/another intel card.....or just buy a card with 4 ports on it.

This of course will mean that i will have to use either an PCI-E x1 or a PCI video card.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I read a post maybe last week that said you can't put a HBA card on the only x16 slot on motherboard that doesn't have onboard video. Is there any truth to this?

That would be BIOS dependent, and I don't know about Gigabyte boards. So long as there is some video capability somewhere it should not cause issues putting a non-Video card in that x16 slot.

Comment: I've used the 16x slot on a Gigabyte workstation MB for other things (SAS HBA) before and it worked just fine. I couldn't guarantee anything.